# Add a particular string (in that case "\\\hline" to prepare a table in latex) at the end of each line of a text file with python

Tags: python, text, line

I want to add a particular string (in that case "\\hline" to prepare a table in latex) at the end of each line of a text file

```
a_file = open("sample.txt", "r")
list_of_lines = a_file.readlines()
for line in range(0, len(list_of_lines)):
  list_of_lines[line] = list_of_lines[line] + r' \\\line'

a_file = open("sample2.txt", "w")
a_file.writelines(list_of_lines)
a_file.close()
```

Here is `sample.txt`:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Here is the output:

```
l1
 \\\linel2
 \\\linel3
 \\\line%
```

What I want is:

```
l1 \\\line
l2 \\\line
l3 \\\line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not removing the linebreak `'\n'` at the end of your lines.

The first line actually looks like this: `'line1\n'`. When you add your string, then the result is `'line1\n \\\line'` which gets displayed with a linebreak in the place of `'\n'`. So you first need to strip the linebreak, then add your string and a linebreak again.

Also, I recommend using context managers (`with`) to open your files , it's much safer than opening and closing the file manually and is considered best practice.

```
with open('sample.txt') as file:
    list_of_lines = file.readlines()
    
for i in range(len(list_of_lines)):
    list_of_lines[i] = list_of_lines[i].rstrip() + r'\\\line' + '\n'
    
with open('sample2.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(list_of_lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `list_of_lines[line].rstrip()`. It seems that the end of line character is being appended in your output.